# How to test if an img tag points to an existing image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm using Cucumber and Capybara for BDD on a RoR application. I have the following feature

```
Feature: List profiles
  In order to know that the people behind the profiles are real people 
  As a lurker
  I want to be able to find who is registed and see their profile picture

Background: Profiles have been added to the database, some with picture attached
  Given some profiles exist
  And  I am on the home page

Scenario: Search by city, avatars should be there
  When I search for a city with profiles
  Then I should see some result profiles with avatar
```

The underlying Capybara steps file contains:

```
Then /^I should see some result profiles with avatar$/ do
  page.should have_css("#profile_search_results .profile img.avatar", :count => some_profiles)
end
```

This step checks that the page contains

```
<div id="#profile_search_results>
  <img class="avatar" src="" />
```

BUT... I also want to check if the image exists (it is not a broken image).

How can I do this in my Capybara steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to check, without having to use Selenium or any other drivers, was to extract the src attribute from the img element (Thanks MrDanA), and check the status code after visiting that URL:

```
page.should have_css("#profile_search_results .profile img.avatar", :count => some_profiles)
img = page.first(:css, "#profile_search_results .profile img.avatar")
visit img[:src]
page.status_code.should be 200
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Capybara's finder methods to find the `img` tag in question, then get it's `src` attribute (e.g `src = element[:src]`). Then you can use Ruby to see if it exists. So all in all it would look something like this:

```
element = page.first(:css, "...")
src = element[:src]
assert File.exists?("#{Rails.root}/#{src}")
```

I haven't tried this to make sure the path given to `File.exists?` is right. But if you print it out first in a test, you'll see what it looks like and whether or not you need to tinker with it a bit.

Comment: Once you have the `img src` it might be more reliable to request it with something like RestClient, and check for a 200 status code and non-zero body, rather than try to figure out the file system location.

Comment: Both MrDanA and Jon M's answers have pointed in the right direction. I  have posted the correct answer as... an answer instead of a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the test is running in Firefox, you can check the `naturalWidth` property of the image. If it is 0, the image is broken.

```
if find('img.avatar')[:naturalWidth] == 0
  raise('image broken')
end
```

Comment: I got `undefined method 'find' for...` when I used  your solution. Do I need to 'require'/'import' any gem?

Comment: @OneTwoThree, the solution assumes you are using Capybara. Depending how you have set it up, you might need to try `page.find`.